# adodb connection not working on virtual machine

Tags: vba, excel, azure-sql-database, adodb

In Excel VBA I used to be able to connect to an Azure database and pull the latest data into the spreadsheet via a virtual machine. However, this no longer works, the same code works and updates when I run it on my desktop.

Code looks like:

```
Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim LinkSQL As String
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11; Password=" & """###""" & "; User ID=###; Initial Catalog=###;" & "Data Source=###;"
LinkSQL = "###"
Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
objMyRecordset.Open LinkSQL
Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
objMyRecordset.Close
objMyConn.Close
```

Thanks

Comment: you can try to connect to the azure data source doing it manually from the Excel data thumb Data > Get Data > From Azure. Once you did this you will be able to retreive the connection string from "Existing connections"

Comment: Can your VM resolve the name to your data source?